# Constructor injecting WPF UserControls without Prism Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, prism

I'm using Prism with Navigation and it works well. Prism injects whatever service I request into the constructor of my Prism view or view-model as expected.  I implement `INavigationAware` to receive any parameters I want.  All good.

But sometimes, I find Prism's loose coupling is a bit *too* loose.  In order to make my `UserControl`s truly re-usable, there is too often there is some view-model property I need to actually *bind* to dirctly in XAML, not merely send as a `NavigationParameter` of a Navigation request.   But I still want access to the services that Prism Controls get constructor-injected for free.

Is there a way to do this that's not a hack?

In other words, sometimes I want

- a regular `UserControl` with DependencyProperties
- that I can just lay out directly in XAML
- that I can *bind to*.
- without any dedicated view model
- that sets itself as its own `DataContext`.

That part is easy.  It's the getting the DI-injection that I cannot work out without a hack.

For example, suppose this simplistic Widget control with one dependency property was mine.

```
namespace MyApp.Controls;
public partial class Widget: UserControl
{
    Widget()  // NOTHING INJECTED
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Scene.DataContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WidgetLabelProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(WidgetLabel), typeof(string)
            typeof(Widget) new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string WidgetLabel
    { 
        get => (string)GetValue(WidgetLabelProperty);
        set => SetValue(WidgetLabelProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Since WPF is constructing this thing, I cannot just add parameters to the constructor like I would with a Prism control

```
Widget(IMyCustomService customService) // **** WILL NOT WORK ***
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Scene.DataContext = this;
}
```

So if I need access to a service, the only solution I've come up with is the hack of adding DependencyProperty.  Like this

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomServiceProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CustomService), typeof(ICustomService)
            typeof(Widget) new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string ICustomService?
    { 
        get => GetValue(CustomServiceProperty) as ICustomService;
        set => SetValue(CustomServiceProperty , value);
    }
```

But of course, that allows the user to leave the property as null.

Is there any better way to this that does not involve a "back door", code-smell type hack  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Would it be crazy or foolish to have a parameterless ctor for the designer, and a parameterized one for DI?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.  Unfortunately this is not an issue with the designer.   The problem is that by just putting my control in XAML, I am bypassing Prism and its control creation process.   The normal, WpfXamlLoader object is the one that is trying to create my control as it is reading it.  Unfortunately it does not know about Prism or the DI container so it sees a constructor that requires an object it does not know how to supply and throws an exception ("No matching constructor found").  I was hoping there was some way to insert some code into this process somehow

Comment: Your hack is the intended solution. If it feels clunky, that's probably because the logic requiring the service should be in some view model.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured.  I'll guess I'll stick with my hack then.    Long struggling with this has made me realize that the clunkiness here is due to the fact that the Prism/loose-coupling/MVVM approach was simply not the right choice for my task.  Prism view/view-model pairs are difficult to customize.  Every time I create one and inject it into some region, someone wants the same one in a completely different region but with items styled differently, removed, added.  That's easy in direct XAML.  A nightmare with a Prism view.